# In cakephp url is showing blank page

Tags: php, url, cakephp

I am working on cakephp2.x . I have a url which works fine on my local server(WAMPP) but when I test it on live server the url is show with a blank page .

I tried it to debug by throwing error in view but it did not affect the url , page still open as blank with no error .

I am using cakephp Auth component for login to application . I am not able to understand why page is showing blank on live server but not in local . Please help me to resolve it .

Its not even showing error on deleting view .
If I add that function in Auth array like below .

```
public function beforeFilter()
     {
           parent::beforeFilter();
           if(!empty($this->Auth))
           {
              $this->Auth->allow('give_ratings');
           }
     }
```

Then the page opens but without session .

Thanks.

Comment: what url you are trying to open?? debug something and see. set debug level to 2 in core.

Comment: Its already set , but nothing is showing up. Url is simple calling to a function in controller.

Comment: There might be some problem with php versions.. can you add the codes for that action??

Comment: did u load the parent::beforefilter in this controller's beforeFilter?

Comment: Also turn the debug level on in config/core.php.

Comment: I get it resolved , in controller the php ?> was ending , I just removed it and it started working.

Answer (score -1):

Well !!! I believe there is some error with mod_rewrite. Please check the link
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#a-note-on-mod-rewrite

I hope it helps !!!

Comment: But its only issue with one page , rest application is working fine .